# Is there any widgets for .docx and .doc viewer in android

Tags: android, apache-poi

I have used Apache poi lib to get the contents of `.docx` and `.doc` file

```
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(stream);
```

Now that I'm showing the doc file in an `editText`.

```
List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphs = document.getParagraphs();
for (XWPFParagraph para : paragraphs) {

                   String s = para.getText() ;

                  System.out.println("para__" + s);
                }
```

I need a .docx and .doc viewer to show the contents of my app,(ie) a view.
I don't want to show it in `edittext` anymore.
Someone help me